# Laravel 7 General error: 1005 Can't create table `edmart`.`cancelled_ex ps` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

Tags: laravel, migration

Hi there is have looked for solutions on Stack an couldn't solve my problem.
I am Using Laravel 7.x. At first my migrations where working properly but when i changer`$table->foreignId("exp_id")->constrained("expenses")->index();` to `$table->foreignId("fk_expense")->constrained("expenses")->index();`, it started to show this error on migration

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `edmart`.`cancelled_ex
 ps` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter table `cancelled
 _exps` add constraint `1` foreign key (`fk_expense`) references `expenses` (`id`
 ))
```

Bellow are the migration file for expenses

```
   public function up(){
       Schema::create('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->id();
           $table->foreignId("user_id")->constrained("users")->index();
           $table->string("desc");
           $table->string("amount");
           $table->string("status");
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   }
```

cancelled expenses migration files

```
 public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('cancelled_exps', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->id();
           $table->foreignId("fk_expense")->constrained("expenses")->index();
           $table->string('viewed');
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   }
```

I tried to remove the database and create a new one but still it failed.
**Update:**
All other migrations work properly except `cancelled_exps`

Comment: You've not posted `edmart` table migration data. You posted `expenses` and `cancelled_exps` table data

Comment: @TalhaF.  `edmart` is not the table, it is database.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the `$table->foreignId("fk_expense")->constrained("expenses")->index()` to

```
$table->foreignId("expences_id")->constrained()
$table->index('expense_id');
```

1. I changed the foreign key column name to `expense_id` hence i don't
   have to specify the expenses table in `constrained()` chained
   method.
2. I also changed the way i was chaining the index.

The whole migration file looks like this....

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('cancelled_exps', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId("expense_id")->constrained();
        $table->index("expense_id");
        $table->string('viewed');
        $table->timestamps();
       });
 }
```